# Display center of circle with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use Leaflet to create circles on a map (geojson).

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
    if (feature.properties.radius) {
        return new L.Circle(latlng, feature.properties.radius);
    }
}
```

How to display the center of these circles?

Thank you !

Comment: Would you elaborate on what you mean by 'display the center of these circles'?

Comment: On this picture -> http://www.carto-sig.com/demo/circle.png I manage to do the 1 but I would like to do as in picture 2.
Show the center of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually return a [Layer Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#layergroup) in the [`pointToLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#geojson-pointtolayer) Leaflet GeoJSON option.

Therefore you can build your Circle as in your code + a marker (or whatever you want to symbolize your center):

```js
L.geoJSON(geoJsonData, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
    if (feature.properties.radius) {
      //return new L.Circle(latlng, feature.properties.radius);
      return L.layerGroup([
        L.circle(latlng, feature.properties.radius),
        L.marker(latlng) // or whatever symbol for circle center
      ]);
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/detaw/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you for your answer but with this technique I can no longer modify the circles with Leaflet Draw.

Comment: That should be a new question. You do not mention it in your current one.